# I am unable to display the data of a selected row of a table using a dialog in sapui5

Tags: sapui5, selected

Once I click on  particular row of a table it should display the details in a dialog.
Here is my code...

```
 onMessageDialogPress: function (oEvent) {

       var oSelectedItem = oEvent.getSource().getParent();
       var oBindingContext = oSelectedItem.getBindingContext();

       if (!this._oDialog){
            this._oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("mycompany.app.MyMasterDetailApp.view.Dialog", this);
       } 

       this._oDialog.setBindingContext(oBindingContext);
       this._oDialog.open();
  }
```

Comment: How you binding in the Dialog.

Comment: Are you using relative or absolute binding in the Dialog?

Answer (score 0):

my problem is solved. I did small changes and now it is working as expected.

This is the working code.

onMessageDialogPress: function (oEvent) {

```
    var oSelectedItem = oEvent.getSource();
     var oBindingContext = oSelectedItem.getBindingContext();



   if (!this._oDialog){
        this._oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("mycompany.app.MyMasterDetailApp.view.Dialog", this);

   } 

    this._oDialog.setBindingContext(oBindingContext);

    this.getView().addDependent(this._oDialog);
     this._oDialog.open();
     },
```

Thanks